# Is Eddington-Lemaître universe relevant to current cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang

[The "Modern Cosmology" article in Scholarpedia.org](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Modern_cosmology) mentions the Eddington-Lemaître universe as an example for "an emergence from a static state" as a possible start of the universe.

Are current observations consistent with EL model?

In other words, could the universe be eternally in the past in static equilibrium between matter and dark energy until, for some reason, it "condenses", "falls" or "bangs" onto the expanding universe?

As I understand, the EL universe is a Big-Bang type universe, but it does not start from a singularity as the Tolman universe.

Unfortunately I do not have access to this article: "[New and old arguments to the Eddington-Lemaǐtre model of the universe](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/asna.2113130302)".

Thanks!.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As I understand your question, "Are current observations consistent with EL model?" the answer is NO. The EL model assumes "emergence from a static state" which (if it did occur) would happen at a very early time when "observation" is impossible.